# How to stop running the code fragment?

Tags: c#

I have an application that read an integer from the text box and search for it in a array. If it finds the value through the array, it must do the rest of calculation but if it can not find it `(value == 0)` it must show a message that `MessageBox.Show("This User ID Does Not Exist");` and stop the calculation and back again for getting the value(I mean, stop the execution and be prepare to get next value ). I wrote following script, but after showing the message it still continues with calculation, how can I stop it?
Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

```
int sc = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_id.Text);
int n = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_noofrecomm.Text);
for (int yu = 0; yu <= 92161; yu++)
{
    int wer = d[yu];
    if (wer == sc)
    {
        userseq = yu;
        break;
    }
}
if (userseq == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("This User ID Does Not Exist");
}
var results = new List<float>(1143600);
for (int z = 0; z < 1143600; z++)
{
    results.Add(dotproduct(userseq, z));
}
```

Comment: When you say "script" what exactly you mean? Is the posted code a function within your program? If so simply returning after showing the messagebox should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return` from your function:

```
if (userseq==0)
{
   MessageBox.Show("This User ID Does Not Exist");
   return;
}
```

Comment: We don't actually know if this is the end of method body I suppose

Comment: You right, if this is not the end of the method then your solution would be more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Use else statement:

```
if (userseq==0)
{
  MessageBox.Show("This User ID Does Not Exist");
}
else
{
   var results = new List<float>(1143600);
   for (int z = 0; z < 1143600; z++)
   {
     results.Add(dotproduct(userseq, z));
   }
}
```